# Read_CSV Import Error in R

Tags: r, csv

I am currently trying to read a csv using the read_csv function.  Using read_csv it fails at the very end of the file (291 MB). This CSV generates nightly and I have run it in before but for some reason today I am receiving an import error:

```
Error in rbind(names(probs), probs_f) : 
(converted from warning) number of columns of result is not a multiple of 
vector length (arg 1)
```

I have tried read.csv and that fails immediately with the following error:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  
: 
(converted from warning) invalid input found on input connection
```

Thoughts on why it would be failing?

Thanks,

Comment: The first error is because of a mismatch between the lengths of the objects you're trying to `rbind`. So likely the number of columns changed in the file (either correctly or incorrectly) without you knowing, or the number of items in `names(probs)` is off. The second error sounds like a character encoding issue. Will be nearly impossible to help without more information. If something is going wrong in the file, you need to start looking at the file directly for strange data.

Comment: Are you sure that the number of elements in the csv file is the same for each row?